# i keep getting a TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly on the 6th line of code

Tags: python

help me with this im new to coding im trying a one of the lessons in "Automate the boring stuff with python" the code goes as follows.

```
# this program says hello and asks for my name.

print('hello world!')

print('what is your name?')  # ask for their name

myName = input()

myName = print()

print('it is good to meet you,' + myName)
print('the length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))
print('what is your age?') # ask for their age
myAge = print()
print('you will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1) + ' in a year. ')
```

Comment: `myAge = print()`. `print` returns `None`. What are you trying to do there? Is that supposed to be `input()`?

Comment: There is nothing at line 6.

Answer (score -1):

Your error seems to be in

```
myAge = print()
```

print is giving info to stdout, not sending info in. The print method expects at least one parameter of a string to print. To print your variable 'myAge' simply:

```
print(myAge)
```

Comment: His error it that you cannot print variable in Python like this `myName = print()`, and because of that he's getting NonType error.